# VSCode I cannot 'Start Debugging' and 'Run Without Debugging'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am currently using python in VSCode and when I press 'Start Debugging' or 'Run Without Debugging' this appears in my screen [image] and as I am a beginner I just pressed the top one (Carbon ComponentS) to Run however this appears in my screen [image] I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I have been trying for hours now but I cannot seem to find a solution. my launch.Json file looks like this [image] What is the problem and how can I fix this? It seems like it is not python's fault because it acts the same when I try to run c++ files too. Thank you.

It appears like this when I press the top right triangle[image]

Comment: 1. Are you actually in a file with a Python extension, like: foo.py when you start the debugger? 2. Can you verify you have a Python environment working? In a Python source file in the VSCode IDE, you should see something like "Python 3.8.2" in the bottom left hand side of the IDE. See: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial

Comment: I am using Code Runner and it works fine when I click the top right triangle button. I have Python 3.9.2 Installed and my program runs well. However, the problem is that when I press 'Start Debugging' it appears as the picture above

Answer (score 0):

1. In VS Code, the debugging function of python code is provided by the "Python" extension. Therefore, please install and use the "Python" extension in VS Code.

   [image]
2. Before debugging python, we need to configure the debugging file "[launch.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_initialize-configurations)":

> ```
>  {
>     // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
>     // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
>     // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
>     "version": "0.2.0",
>     "configurations": [
>         {
>             "name": "Python: Current File",
>             "type": "python",
>             "request": "launch",
>             "program": "${file}",
>             "console":"integratedTerminal",
>         }
>     ]
> }
> ```

debug:

[image]

Please refer to this document: [Python debug configurations in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging).